# Return object result

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, object

I need to get the result of this object, I've tried `json.count(id_reported)` and `json['count(id_reported)']` but none worked.

```js
const json = { 
  'count(id_reported)': 21 
};
    
//console.log(json.count(id_reported));
console.log(json['count(id_reported)']);
```

Comment: `json['count(id_reported)']` works just fine.

Comment: You may need to update your question with more details--as-is it's unclear what actual problem you're having since the code works as shown.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Javascript, Typescript and so in Express in the end, its easy to handle such things.

```
var myObject = { 
  'count': 21 
}

myObject = JSON.parse(myObject);
console.log(myObject.count);
```

The `JSON.parse` is only needed, if you object is a string. Is it a Javascript object you do not need to parse.

The count(id_reported) part I don't understand. If your object looks like this in the end:

```
{
  count(1): 1,
  count(2): 2,
}
```

and you don't know the structure at all you can use a for loop:

```
for (let data in myObject) {
  console.log(data); // data will be the key; so count(1) as example
}
```

See the **in** keyword in the for loop. This will give you the key. The **on** keyword otherwise gives the object in an array as example.